# Yii2 ActiveForm for yii\httpclient\CurlTransport

Tags: json, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, active-form

I am trying to do CRUD operations but the data is not stored in the database. I am connecting to a third party api using yii\httpclient\CurlTransport - json format.

I was able to create READ operation with this request and put it on the GRIDVIEW dataprovider

```
$client = new Client(['transport' => 'yii\httpclient\CurlTransport',]);
        $request_sites= $client->createRequest()
            ->setMethod('POST')
            ->setFormat(Client::FORMAT_JSON)
            ->setUrl('https://example.com/remote/json.php?sites')
            ->setData('primary_id' => $id)->setOptions([
                CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 5,
                CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 10,
            ])->send();
        $array_sites= Json::decode($request_sites->content);
```

My issue now is how can I work with UPDATE if my datasource is json and not a loaded MODEL.

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'sample')->textInput() ?>
```

For loading the data into the the form field I will need to create a request to the third party api. then once loaded the users should be able to update the form(which I think is another request to the third partyapi).

sample API endpoints: sites_add, sites_update, sites_delete

Is there any reference for sample implementation or documentation related to this?

Comment: You need to load this JSON data into model - then you have standard form and validation support.

Comment: @rob006 I tried $model = $array_sitest['response']; but I got error "Call to a member function isAttributeRequired() on array"

the api returns something like this.
{
    "code": "ok",
    "message": "",
    "response": {
        "domain_id": "29"
     } 
}

Comment: You may need `$model->setAttributes($response['response'], false)`.

Comment: @rob006 it returned an another error. "Call to a member function setAttribute() on array"

Comment: do I put it before $form->field line?